# How to add a metric summary to a canned tensorflow Estimator?

Tags: python, api, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, high-level

I want to run one of the [TensorFlow metrics](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics) on my labels and Estimator predictions as a summary to display in Tensorboard.  Is there an easy way to do this, or does it require defining a Custom Estimator and model_fn?